# How can I set up the <Select/> to start to suggest Options only when user type more than 0 chars?

Tags: antd

**How can I set up the  to start to suggest Options only when user type more than 0 chars ?**

I mean:

1. `<Select/>` is focused, but empty -> do not show suggested Options
2. `<Select/>` is focused, 1 char in input -> suggest Options

Comment: There is already an [option available](https://ant.design/components/select/#components-select-demo-search-box). Are you looking for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution where inserted options are removed from suggestions
https://codepen.io/Sergei_Volynkin/pen/rQXJvX

```
render() {
    const { selectedItems } = this.state
    const filteredOptions = OPTIONS.filter(o => !selectedItems.includes(o))
    return (
      <Select
        mode="multiple"
        placeholder="Inserted are removed"
        value={selectedItems}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={{ width: 280 }}
      >
        {filteredOptions.map(o => <Select.Option key={o} value={o}>{o}</Select.Option>)}
      </Select>
    )
  }
```

[image: solution]